# A word for one who goes against conventional wisdom because it makes sense to do so?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word for someone who goes against conventional wisdom because they have sufficient evidence that it makes sense to do so.  The only words I can think of, like contrarian, or hipster, have the connotation of being rebellious for the sake of being rebellious, not because it is the logical thing to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ***Scientist**?*

Comment: That would fit, but I was thinking more in the context of everyday life. I'm trying to think of a good example of what I'm looking for.  I'll update if I do.

Comment: More generally than "scientist", here's "empricist". And specifically one who goes against conventional wisdom is an "iconoclast", although that's sort of tangential; that really just means someone who goes against tradition (it doesn't say anything about why).

Comment: "Pragmatist", perhaps?

Comment: anarchist/terrorist

Comment: What type of "sense" - there's "rational" sense, "artistic or aesthetic"  sense, the "emotional' sense of lovers, if you have a particular type of sense in mind can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

A **freethinker** is:

> n. a person who forms opinions on the basis of reason, independent of
>   authority or tradition. [1685–95]

[[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/freethinker)]

Comment: Worth noting that the "freethinker" community and "atheist" community are (if not completely the same) strongly related in the U.S. Not sure if religious people realize that here, but certainly if you're speaking with atheists and call yourself a freethinker they'll assume you're also atheist. Worth letting the OP know that so they can avoid confusion.

Comment: Perhaps the atheists are aware that others have different opinions.

Comment: Sure. Although those with differing opinions on the definition of this word would be [unfamiliar with the definition of the philosophical movement underlying this word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freethought): "Regarding religion, freethinkers hold that there is insufficient evidence to support the existence of supernatural phenomena.".

Comment: Not necessarily. Those with opinions not exactly matching fundamentalist atheists about permitted senses of 'freethinker' may realise that the belief that words cannot be used with meanings different from earlier ones is the etymological fallacy.

Comment: Of course you can use whatever definitions you want for whatever words you choose. But if you use this word to mean something nonstandard, prepare to be misunderstood by everyone.

Comment: I take your point, and would usually add 'in the more general sense', but refuse to yield further ground to people hijacking words.  From [Yahoo! Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071019080528AAWf5xo): _Best Answer_:  **Atheist** : Doesn't believe in Gods // **Freethinker**: Doesn't believe in dogmatic adherence to beliefs. 

They are two non-identical, intersecting sets. 

By that I mean there are atheists who aren't freethinkers, atheists who are freethinkers, and freethinkers who aren't atheists.
... Vishal ·

Answer (score 1):

I think **Reformer** or **Innovator** sound less rebellious than other words that may easily come to mind.

Comment: Suppose the subject happens to believe the *only logical thing to do* is to return to an *ancient* dogma?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It would still work; reform doesn't necessarily mean you're imposing something new- in fact, it implies that you're salvaging something that already exists. I'm sure if you asked any of the people trying to get creationism taught in science classes whether they wanted to reform the educational system, they'd say yes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for **iconoclast**.

Answer (score 1):

See this relevant page, centered on "maverick":

[The Paradox of Countertransference: You and Me, Here and Now](https://books.google.ca/books?id=R9IcBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA76&dq=%22maverick%22%20synonyms&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CqYTVbfTJIzdoATSjIHYAg&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22maverick%22%20synonyms&f=false)
 By Carol Holmes

Answer (score 0):

Pioneer would be appropriate if the person is doing something new, but **maverick** would apply to almost any situation.

https://www.google.com/webhp?source=search_app#q=maverick

**maverick**: 
noun
1.
an unorthodox or independent-minded person.

Answer (score 0):

I use ['antinomian'](https://www.startpage.com/do/search?cat=web&language=english&query=antinomian&pl=opensearch) but it seems to have a rather technical sense in theology so I am extending its dictionary definition.

Comment: _Why_ would you use this word? And what source backs you up?